# Как управлять потоком соединения из другого активити

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. Пишу android приложение, управление по Wi-Fi android камерой с другого телефона. Сервер, где открыта камера, слушает входящие соединения. Затем авторизует клиента по специальному UUID приложения и заданному паролю. В рамках одного соединения отправляются и команды и превью камеры. Клиент, запуская активити и выбирая сервер, вводит пароль и соединяется. Если пароль правильный, запускается новое активити, где будет отрисовка кадров превью. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно будет управлять клиенту уже открытым соединением (потоком) в новом активити? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте соединение и взаимодействие с камерой через `Service`. И можно будет на каждой активити делать `bind` к `Service`.

[Биндинг к Service](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/162-urok-97-service-binding-serviceconnection.html)

[Обмен данными при биндинге](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/163-urok-98-service-lokalnyj-binding.html)

Comment: Хорошо, большое спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.